# serde - Multiple defaults grouped together?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to load a Toml file with Serde, it contains multiple booleans, I want to default them all to false if not found in the text file.

My implementation currently is:

```
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all="PascalCase")]
pub struct SomeConfigStruct {
     // This one *must* exist, non optional, non defaulted.
    class_name : String, 

    #[serde(default = "default_boolean")]
    parent_in_constructor : bool,

    #[serde(default = "default_boolean")]
    set_user_texts : bool,

    #[serde(default = "default_boolean")]
    singleton : bool, 

    #[serde(default = "default_boolean")]
    use_enum_types : bool,
}
```

How can I do something in the lines of:

```
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all="PascalCase")]
pub struct SomeConfigStruct {
    class_name : String,

    #[serde(type = bool, default = "default_boolean")]
    parent_in_constructor : bool,
    set_user_texts : bool,
    singleton : bool, 
    use_enum_types : bool,
}
```

[edit, new member on the Struct to better exemplify what I need.]

Comment: Just a quick clarification: I strongly believe such a macro would need to be applied to `SomeConfigStruct`, not a specific field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated for new constraints**

I don't know of such a macro, to my knowledge that doesn't exist. I can offer an alternative solution though.

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
pub struct SomeConfigStruct {
    class_name: String,

    #[serde(default)]
    #[serde(flatten)]
    defaulting_values: SomeConfigStructDefaulting,
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
#[serde(default)]
pub struct SomeConfigStructDefaulting {
    parent_in_constructor: bool,
    set_user_texts: bool,
    singleton: bool,
    use_enum_types: bool,
}

// This will be called to fill in missing spots in defaulting_values.
// Will also be called, if defaulting_values is missing altogether.
impl Default for SomeConfigStructDefaulting {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let default_boolean = true;
        Self {
            parent_in_constructor: default_boolean,
            set_user_texts: default_boolean,
            singleton: default_boolean,
            use_enum_types: default_boolean,
        }
    }
}
```

This for sure doesn't decrease line count, but it does fix `default_boolean` to one value, if that was your primary concern.

This way, your serialized representation will still look the same, and you can easily write wrappers to not have to write `some_config_struct.defaulting_values` in your actual code.

Comment: I'v found one RFC from rust that perhaps will allow default values on the structs, let's see if that will help. :) I can't really use the Default in my specific case because *one* of the values should panic if not in the file being read by serde, and if I define a Default, I need to default for *every* value.

Comment: Can you link that RFC please? I couldn't find it. One workaround would be to factor all fields that have a default into an inner struct, which could then be [flattened](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html) into the outer struct. This could also be systematicallly done with a proc macro.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1806 and https://github.com/Centril/rfcs/pull/19

Comment: Thank you, the 'flatten' is what I missed. :)